# Generate Body Skin Texture from Head Skin Texture

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders

I want to combine a character's body with another character's head. While tweaking the base skin color and brightness will get me far, the skin details and shading is still way off between both body parts. Is there a way to generate a skin texture for the body that is more similar to the one of the head?

Any hints or thoughts are appreciated, thanks in advance[image]

Comment: I think this question is not a good fit for Blender SE. You can try [Photography SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/), or [GameDevelopment SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/), but be sure to read their Help section on what's on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably best way to do this would be to import both textures into PS or Gimp or whatever, then change Blend Mode on the layer with the color you want to *Color*, in Gimp it's *LCh Color*. It basically just overrides the color values in the layer below with the color values from the one above.

The two skin textures side-by-side:

[image]

With color blend mode:

[image]