# Unable to copy torso skin texture to face

Tags: mesh, texturing, faces

I imported torso(.glb) and head(.obj) separately and combined them by adding to armature successfully. The issue am facing is Head Texture and torse texture are completely different.

how do i apply torso skin texture to face.

[image]

I tried using **Shader editor** by adding torso skin image texture and adjusted the parameters of **Principled BSDF** but it was distorted. Pls suggest what best can be done here

Even tried this [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271262/generate-body-skin-texture-from-head-skin-texture) but no luck

Head and torso [attached](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Wv84g2q_SOD8r7fKcs8XFhXdxS5eTTbJ/view?usp=sharing):

Comment: Hello please pack the images (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file?

Comment: You probably will be best off doing this in an image editor, as you need to color correct either diffuse texture.

Comment: @moonboots i added Head and torso to the Post

Comment: The torso has another material, you need to give the same material to the torso, but it also needs to be properly unwrapped so that the UV covers a skin part of the image

Comment: @moonboots can u share some video this pls... my workaround is not working properly..

Comment: Your file is not available anymore, also it's not clear what you want to do, you should assign the same material to the body faces as the head faces, unwrap the body again, and in the UV Editor, then make sure that these faces overlap the good color, or repaint the body in the 3D view

Answer (score 0):

got it

by changing the materials able to fix the issue...

@moonboots thanks for the input